# MySQL: how to pick a value from one GROUP BY level and broadcast across all levels

Tags: mysql, grouping

I have a MYSQL table like this

```
person giftaid postcode year amount
A      1       NULL     2010     10
A      0       XY123    2010     15
A      0       NULL     2011     10
A      0       NULL     2011     20
B      0       NULL     2010     20
B      0       NULL     2010      1
B      0       NULL     2011     30
C      1       NULL     2010     50
C      1       AB345    2011     80
```

And I want to sum the amounts given by each person in each year, but take the giftaid and postcode values for that person *from any year*. I.e. I need

```
person ever_giftaided any_postcode year sum
A      1              XY123        2010 25
A      1              XY123        2011 30
B      0              NULL         2010 21
B      0              NULL         2011 30
C      1              AB345        2010 50
C      1              AB345        2011 80
```

Note that although person A didn't agree to giftaid in 2011, because they agreed in 2010, I'm happy to fill out the `ever_giftaided` column with a 1 for all years, and take any non-null postcode too.

If I do a simple `GROUP BY person, year`, and use `MAX(giftaid) AS ever_giftaided, MAX(postcode) AS any_postcode`, then in the second row, person A gets a `0` for `ever_giftaided`, and NULL for `any_postcode`, because the group by clause doesn't transfer information between the groupings by `person`, but by the groupings of the combinations of `person` and `year`. I could simply `GROUP BY person`, but then I don't get the amounts broken down by year. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join two queries. One groups by `person`, the other groups by `person, year`.

```
SELECT t1.person, t1.ever_giftaided, t1.any_postcode, t2.year, t2.sum
FROM (
    SELECT person, MAX(giftaided) AS ever_giftaided, MAX(postcode) AS any_postcode
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY person) AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT person, year, SUM(amount) AS sum
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY person, year) AS t2 ON t1.person = t2.person
```

You can also do one of the groupings in the main query:

```
SELECT t1.person, MAX(giftaided) AS ever_giftaided, MAX(postcode) AS any_postcode,
         t2.year, t2.sum
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT person, year, SUM(amount) AS sum
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY person, year) AS t2 ON t1.person = t2.person
GROUP BY t1.person
```